# NSArray initialization methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, nsarray

What is the difference between initializing array with

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray array];
```

and

```
NSArray * array = @[];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSArray * array = @[];` is the new way of doing `NSArray * array = [NSArray array];`

Comment: 1. Unrelated to the version of Xcode (rather related to the version of the language/standard/compiler used, of which Xcode is neither one). 2. "It's the same as `NSString *string = @"";`" - I don't think so. The former creates an array, the latter creates a string.

Comment: A good guess, but mostly incorrect.  First statement is correct, rest is wrong.

Comment: yes, that is correct. Wrote my answer to quickly. Edited my answer. My bad.

Answer (score 9):

`@[]` is shorthand for:

```
id a = nil;
NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:&a count:0];
```

Which is really just shorthand for `[NSArray array]`, for all intents and purposes.

This is a feature added in a particular version of the compiler (and doesn't actually require runtime support for *this* particular syntax).

It is *not at all like* the `@""` shorthand in that `@""` produces a *compile time constant* and will cause *no messaging at runtime*.   In fact, `@""` (any `@"sequence"`) is a special case in that it emits a compile time constant that is realized in the runtime with zero messaging; zero dynamism.   A `@"..."` is more similar to an Objective-C class than it is to a regular instance of an object.

Comment: I think @"" produces an NSString object not a compile time constant.

Comment: Nope;  it really is a compile time constant that is loaded via the dynamic linker just like classes and other compile time emitted data.  There is no messaging involved.