# How are these NSArray initialization methods different?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSArray initialization methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483531/nsarray-initialization-methods)

What is the difference between initializing array with

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray array];
```

and

```
NSArray * array = @[];
```

Comment: Did you watch the WWDC 2011 videos (101 - Welcome announcement thing)? It details this exactly

Comment: even better video: [Objective-C Advancements In-Depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=322)

Comment: I like [bbum's explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14484133/475228) of @[] ...

Comment: Also, searching this site before posting wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions are generally equivalent.

[Clang's documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#caveats) lists a caveat for object literals:

> Objects created using the literal or boxed expression syntax are not guaranteed to be uniqued by the runtime, but nor are they guaranteed to be newly-allocated. As such, **the result of performing direct comparisons against the location of an object literal (using ==, !=, <, <=, >, or >=) is not well-defined**. This is usually a simple mistake in code that intended to call the `isEqual:` method (or the `compare:` method).

As the documentation states, the caveat listed above only occurs when using direct comparison operators between objects, which is almost always not the intended action anyway. This behavior shouldn't matter, so the two can almost always be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

The `@[]` is the shortcut  for `[NSArray array]` in **modern Objective C**

Please check [**The_Basics_of_Modern_Objective-C**](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Basics_of_Modern_Objective-C) for a better understanding.

In my knowledge when you use the @[] this will be equivalent to the corresponding Class methods. Means:

```
@[]          = [NSArray array];
@[@"M",@"P"] = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"M",@"P",nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

These both are similar.

`[NSArray array]` and `@[]` creates and returns an empty array.

`@[]` is an new feature added in Objective-C. It boxes several kind of objects, and gives you flexibility of shortcut notation.

> When using Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 or later, arrays, dictionaries, and
>   numbers (NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber classes) can be created using
>   literal syntax instead of methods. Literal syntax uses the @ symbol
>   combined with [], {}, (), to create the classes mentioned above,
>   respectively.

More references [Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/pso6x/xcode_43_released/c3s2n5r), [Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)